# Is it possible to define sub-project dependencies in main build.gradle file?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, build.gradle, classpath

In eclipse gradle it is possible to add dependencies to all sub-projects like so:

```
def dependency_p = new org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.ProjectDependency('/dependency-1')
dependency_p.exported = true

eclipse.classpath.file {
   whenMerged { classpath -> 
      classpath.entries << dependency_p
   }
}
```

My question: is it possible to add certain dependencies to certain sub-project from the main build.gradle file?
Something like:

```
subproject.eclipse.classpath.file {
   whenMerged { classpath -> 
      classpath.entries << dependency_p
   }
}
```